# What is a "trooferism"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

What is a **trooferism**?

Personally, I found it in [context](http://shittywebcomics.tumblr.com/post/106067988284/comic-tropes-that-everyone-else-needs-to-get-over):

> Comic tropes that everyone else needs to get over:
>
> [...]
>
> - Hysterical moral cause from 6 months ago that everyone already realized was bullshit, but in the comic is portrayed positively (9/11 **trooferism**, occupy wall street, feminism, trannies).

I can find quite a few occurrences of the word, but no definition. The closest I think was the heavily biased entry for *[Troofer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=troofer)* in Urban Dictionary:

> Term of abuse used by Bush supporters against anyone who is openly disbelieving of the Bush Administration's heavily propagandised 9/11 fairytale. The term is used most often in a derogatory way as an ad hominem by neocon trolls in order to avoid dealing with the facts, commonsense, and supporting links presented by 9/11 sceptics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Troofer](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/troofer), from  [truther:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/truther)  (from MacMillan Dict)

> - a person who does not believe the accepted explanation of a particular event and who believes that they know the true facts about what happened.

*Trooferism* is clearly a noun from troofer and refers to the contrarian, unorthodox views of stated truths.

- Category Archives: [Trooferism](http://junipersec.wordpress.com/category/trooferism/page/2/)
- The moral ‘[trooferism](http://cifwatch.com/2013/04/24/richard-falk-and-the-moral-trooferism-of-the-guardians-seumas-milne/)’ of Richard Falk and the Guardian’s Seumas Milne.
- Lauren Booth Endorses Boston Bombing [Trooferism](http://www.israellycool.com/2013/04/23/lauren-booth-endorses-boston-bombing-trooferism/)

Answer (score 1):

This is an 'amusing' misspelling of *truther*, itself used only in the idiom "9/11 truther", a person who believes one of the many conspiracy theories surrounding the September 2001 attacks.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a derogatory term for 9/11 "Truthers", who believe and/or circulate various conspiracy theories about the "truth" of the World Trade Center attack.

Personally, I consider "Truther" itself to be sufficient denunciation of these deluded souls.

Answer (score 0):

[th-fronting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting) (changing 'th' to 'f') is typical of varieties in the UK, not the US (except for maybe AAVE and some rare related Southern US accents). This term 'trooferism' is, strangely, what people in the UK call, in imitation of their own non-standard dialects, the 'truthers' in the US.